# How do I test retry attempts in PromiseKit?

Tags: ios, swift, testing, xctest, promisekit

I'm trying to implement a network call using PromiseKit and if it fails I want it to retry several times before giving up. I have done this using the PromiseKit [documentation](https://github.com/mxcl/PromiseKit/blob/master/Documentation/CommonPatterns.md#retry--polling) and it seems to work well enough. However, I have encountered issue when trying to test my implementation.

This is what my test looks like:

```
func testFetch_withFirstAttemptFailed_shouldFetchEndpointFromDataProviderAgain() {
    // Given
    let expectation = self.expectation(description: "")

    let failingAttempt = Promise<String>.pending()
    let succeedingAttempt = Promise<String>.pending()
    dataProviderMock.fetchReturnValues = [failingAttempt, succeedingAttempt]

    let _: Promise<String> = sut.fetch(EndpointMock())
    XCTAssertEqual(dataProviderMock.fetchInvokeCount, 1)

    // When
    failingAttempt.resolver.reject(MockError.error)

    failingAttempt.promise.catch { (_) in
        self.wait(for: 3)
        succeedingAttempt.resolver.fulfill("success")
    }

    _ = succeedingAttempt.promise.done { [weak self] result in
        // Then
        XCTAssertEqual(result, "success")
        guard let dataProvider = self?.dataProviderMock else { XCTFail(); return }
        XCTAssertEqual(dataProvider.fetchInvokeCount, 2)
        expectation.fulfill()
    }

    self.wait(for: [expectation], timeout: 4)
}
```

I have mocked my data provider to return different promises depending on which attempt it's currently trying. I want to check that `fetch` is invoked a second time if the first attempt fails.

In particular I'm dissatisfied with the `wait` part of the test but since I'm noob I don't know when to fulfill the succeeding attempt. My SUT has a retry delay of two seconds by default but I can inject another in my test if I wish. Ideally I don't want to wait at all so if anyone knows in what closure I can fulfill the succeeding attempt please let me know.

I've tried using the same `recover` function used in the retry implementation but it seems that fulfilling it there executes the body before fetch is invoked so my assertion fails.